# Is $frac(n^{\sqrt{2}})$ dense in $[0,1]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $$s_n:=frac(n^{\sqrt{2}})$$ $n=1,2,3,\cdots$

> Is $s_n$ dense in $[0,1]$ ?

The number $$12230575^{\sqrt{2}}$$ is almost an integer, but I do not know whether we can get arbitary close to an integer. And even this would not show that we can get arbitary near to any given number $t\in [0,1]$. For example $$frac(4555670^{\sqrt{2}})$$ is very near to $0.\overline{676}$. Any ideas ?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Doesn't $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ usually denote the floor function?

Comment: "frac" is the fractional part : $frac(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$